# how do I write a JavaScript program to find 1st January is being a Sunday between 2014 and 2050

Tags: javascript, date-fns

Please how do I write a JavaScript program to find 1st January is being a Sunday between 2014 and 2050 using date fns library.

Comment: Please include what you have tried, to get people interested. After all where here to help and get help with what we try to do when we have problems, not to have other people solve our problems completely, as per site guidelines :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any library, try something like this:

```js
let year = 2014;
while(year <= 2050) {
  if(new Date(year, 0, 1).getDay() === 0) {
    break;
  }
  year++;
}

console.log(year);
```